# How do I adjust the volume of a specific audio channel in Pygame?

Tags: python, audio, pygame

You only need to adjust the volume for this background audio track (**specific audio channel "0"**) in `pygame.mixer.Channel(0)`

The program works with this and without it `pygame.mixer.music.set_volume (0.1)`

Also, with the help `pygame.mixer.music.set_volume (0.1)` it is possible to reduce the volume without specifying the channel through `mixer.music.load("n.mp3")` and `mixer.music.play()`

```
import pygame

from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("n.mp3")
pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(pygame.mixer.Sound("n.mp3"), (-1))
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the volume of a channel with [`set_volume()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel) method of the [`pygame.mixer.Channel`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel) object:

> Set the volume (loudness) of a playing sound. When a channel starts to play its volume value is reset. This only affects the current sound. The value argument is between 0.0 and 1.0.

e.g.:

```py
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("n.mp3")
channel = pygame.mixer.Channel(0)
channel.play(sound, -1)
channel.set_volume(0.1)
```

Comment: Your answer was is helpful with pyinstaller compilation (my addition was in not helpful with pyinstaller compilation :D)

Answer (score 0):

Decided!

```
import pygame

from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("n.mp3")
pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(pygame.mixer.Sound("n.mp3"), (-1))
pygame.mixer.Channel(0).set_volume(0.3)
```

Comment: What is the difference to my answer?